# restore table structure from idb file, bymistakely deleted frm file

Tags: mysql, innodb

I am using mysql and innodb storage engine, bymistakely I deleted .frm file from application and now have just .ibd file. Not able to restore the table structure as frm file is not there.

Is there any way to get the .frm file back, or how should I restore table without .frm file, I have table structure in .sql file

Any help on this please

Comment: do you have mysql 5.6?

Comment: @ravnur thanks for the reply, no I am using 5.5

Comment: create temp database; run your script to create table in temp database; copy frm file from from temp folder to actual. Is it works for you?

Comment: @ravnur - tried that, it gives me error `ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'db.drls_old' doesn't exist`

Answer (score 1):

On 5.5 there are two ways. Either a fake frm file as ravnur suggested or dump records from the .ibd file with https://github.com/twindb/undrop-for-innodb

The most reliable way would be import the table space in 5.6. Upgrade to 5.6 is not a bad idea anyway.

Comment: sounds promising, I wl try dumping records from the .ibd file and will upgrade to 5.6, thanks again